# The sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ defined by $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{a_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I tried to prove the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ recursively defined by $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{a_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence, but in vain. Here's my attempt. By induction, we can easily show that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $1\leq a_n\leq 2$. Now fix $k\in\mathbb{N}$. I want to finish the proof by demonstrating that $|a_{n+k+1}-a_{n+1}|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. A little algebra tells us that
$$|a_{n+k+1}-a_{n+1}|=\frac{|a_{n+k}-a_{n}|}{a_{n+k}a_{n}}\leq\frac{|a_{n+k}-a_{n}|}{1\cdot 1}\leq\cdots\leq|a_{k+1}-a_{1}|\leq2+1.$$
Things didn't work as I had expected. Before obtaining the useless result, I had been hoping to see something like
$$|a_{n+k+1}-a_{n+1}|\leq\frac{2+1}{b^{n+1}}\text{ with  }b>1.$$
Then I could fulfill the task by letting $n\to\infty$. What's wrong with my attempt? Thank you.

Comment: So all you are missing is a better minoration of $a_n$ (and $a_{n+k}$) than 1 for $n\geq 2$. Using your majoration from the first round of induction, can't you get one ?

Comment: Hint: consider two steps and confront $a_{n+2}$ with $a_n$

Comment: Showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_{n+k}-a_n|=0$ for every $k$ is not enough to show that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich is correct - for a concrete example, consider $a_k = \ln k$. Even if you require $a$ to be bounded, you can still find a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you, but I really need something to get the work done. What I have done is to rephrase the definition of a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a_n\le 2$, one has
$$ a_{n+1}-\frac32=\left(1+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)-\frac32=\frac{2-a_n}{2a_n}\ge0 $$
and hence
$$ \frac32\le a_n\le 2, \forall n\ge2. $$
Now you can have your result for $b=\frac32$.